# Размытость текста кнопки

Tags: html, css

Как убрать размытость в надписи Sign In.?
[image: Unnamder]

```
.btn-prym, a.btn-prym, button.btn-prym {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    padding: 11px 22px;
    background-color: #3c9ff0;
    transition: background-color .2s ease;
    text-transform: none;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

.btn, a.btn, button.btn {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 20px;
    /* text-transform: uppercase; */
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

Comment: Скорее никак, это особенности движка браузера.

Comment: а если убрать `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased`?

Comment: Эффекта не изменился